# Ordered relations in a TypeORM, Postgres application

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am building an application with NestJS, TypeORM and Postgres. I have two entities: Recipe and Procedure. A Recipe may have many Procedures (such as 'Mix ingredients', 'Bake batter', 'Serve'), but a Procedure is only related to one Recipe. The order of the Procedures is defined by the user, may be updated arbitrarily and is important to store.

How do I model this, specifically the ordering of the procedures? Currently, I have the following (simplified) models:

```
@Entity({ name: 'recipe' })
export class Recipe extends OrganizationOwnedBaseEntity {
  @Column({ name: 'name' })
  name: string;

  // One recipe can have many procedures
  @OneToMany(() => Procedure, (procedure) => procedure.recipe, {
    cascade: ['remove', 'insert'],
  })
  procedures: Procedure[];
}


@Entity({ name: 'procedure' })
export class Procedure extends OrganizationOwnedBaseEntity {
  @Column({ name: 'description' })
  description: string;

  // Many procedures can belong to one recipe
  @ManyToOne(() => Recipe, (recipe) => recipe.procedures)
  recipe: Recipe;
}
```

A possible solution is to add a column to Procedure for Order and then keep track of the ordering using that, but that leads to issues when updating the order of one Procedure impacting the order of other Procedures (ie moving a Procedure from order: 10 to order: 1, I may then need to increment all other Procedure orders by 1).

Is there a way to just store an ordered array of FKs in the Recipe entity and update that when needed?

Comment: Afaik typeorm supports storing arrays for postgres. So you can have an array property on the recipe entity. But you may not have a check constraint for it and writing the ordering query will not be an easy task.